# Unable to Create New GCP Endpoints in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run

I'm using Cloud Run, Endpoints and Cloud Functions to build an API service. There are multiple endpoints running completely fine, but I'm no longer able to deploy any new endpoints.

The Cloud Run environment has an error that prevents it from making a call to the corresponding Cloud Function. Oddly enough, all other endpoints work fine, but I'm unable to create new endpoints.

I found this article: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errors but it's only for the BAD_GATEWAY error code.
All code is deployed completely fine. No errors in deploying the Cloud Function, Cloud Run or Open API yaml file.

Error in response:

```
{
 "code": 13,
 "message": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "application"
  }
 ]
}
```

Error in Cloud Run:

```
5#5: *33 invalid URL prefix in "", client: xxxxx, server: , request: "GET /user HTTP/1.1", host: "[my cloud run host]" 
GET 500 404 B4 ms python-requests/2.22.0 [cloud run host]/user
```

The main.py file:

```
def user(request):

    return "Ok"
```

The yaml file:

```
/user:
 x-google-backend:
    address: https://[cloud functions host]/user
 get:
  summary: Retrieves a user.
  operationId: getUser
  responses:
    '200':
      description: A successful response
    '400':
      description: BAD_REQUEST
```

Comment: Are there any errors being logged to Stackdriver Logging?

Comment: Check out the errors under "Error in Cloud Run"

Answer (score 0):

If we look at your YAML:

```
/user:
 x-google-backend:
    address: https://[cloud functions host]/user
 get:
  summary: Retrieves a user.
  operationId: getUser
  responses:
    '200':
      description: A successful response
    '400':
      description: BAD_REQUEST
```

... pay particular attention to the `x-google-backend` section.  Notice that this exists *within* the `/user` path section.  Now notice that the address is a URL *with a path*.  You don't want a path part in the URL, just the address of the host (and optional port).  Change your start of your YAML to:

```
/user:
 x-google-backend:
    address: https://[cloud functions host]
```

(The `/user` portion was removed from the `address` line)

Comment: [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#x-google-backend) about the x-google-backend, it has to be only address of the host.

Comment: @sotis I think that may have changed. It now seems that if x-google-backend is inside a path, the default is to not append the path to the `x-google-backend` `address`: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#understanding_path_translation